# Implement votes for a page in a Sharepoint 2007 web?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I develop a website in Sharepoint 2007. I have pages that have a richhtmlfield with content. I need to add the possibility to add comments by any user and the option to rate the page with a dropdownlist with values from 1-5, then sum all the votes and show a global rate for the page.
i don't know how to do this in Sharepoint or what are my options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the [Document Rating System](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SharePoint%20-%20Document%20Rating%20System&referringTitle=Home) of the [SharePoint Tool Basket](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/) a try.

> This project allows authenticated users to rate :
>
> - custom lists, document libraries, picture libraries, issue lists, calendars, links
> - discussion boards
> - pages.
> - Blog posts
> - Moderator module
> - The system also contains a site definition and is now available in English, French & Dutch

Answer (score 1):

Also the Podcasting Toolkit for SharePoint http://www.codeplex.com/pks (developed by Microsoft) contains a nice rating control.